# Add Additional Property to Neptune DB

Tags: graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am trying to add additional property called "insert_date" to the existing vertices and edges. I tried

```
g.V().setProperty('insert_date',datetime('2020-10-06'))
```

Error:

```
{
  "requestId": "33cf8df5-3cbe-41ac-b650-5752debec04d",
  "code": "MalformedQueryException",
  "detailedMessage": "Query parsing failed at line 1, character position at 10, error message : token recognition error at: 'rop'"
}
```

I am trying the above command from Neptune Notebook.

It just adds new vertices with insert_date property. But I did not find the way to alter existing vertices or edges.

Please suggest if this is possible. As I want to implement delta extraction so that I can extract only new vertices or edges every time I run ETL.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide some additional details on this question around Neptune adding a new vertex?  The code above will find a vertex with the id of `1234` and if it finds one it will set the `insert_date` property to `2020-10-06'.

Comment: I have updated the command in Question. Actually i am trying to add new property to existing vertices which is insert_date property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a property to an existing vertex in Gremlin you use the [property()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#addproperty-step) step.  For example, if you wanted to add a property `insert_date` to a vertex with the id of `A` you would use the following statement:

`g.V('A').property('insert_date', '2020-10-06')`

The `property()` step will add or update the specified property to the new value.  This will occur for all the current elements being passed in.  For example, if you only wanted to update the elements that did not have an `insert_date` property you could do this via:

`g.V().hasNot('insert_date').property('insert_date', '2020-10-06')`

In each of these example the property will be added as part of an array of values.  If you want to set the property to only contain a single value then you can use the `property()` step overload that takes the cardinality like this:

`g.V('A').property(Cardinality.single, 'insert_date', '2020-10-06')`

One thing to note in the code you have listed above.  While Neptune does support the `datetime()` function for string-based queries, if you are not using a GLV then you will need to create this value and pass in a Native Date/Time as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/best-practices-gremlin-datetime-glv.html).

Answer (score 0):

Below Command worked to add additional properties to existing Graph.

```
g.V().property("insert_date","2020-01-01 00:00:00")
```

Comment: This will add or update the `insert_date` property for every Vertex in the graph to '2020-01-01 00:00:00'.  Not sure if that is the intended behavior or not.